# Aufofac InstancePerOwned different scopes

Tags: c#, scope, instance, autofac

Is there a way to register same type with two differnt scopes like this?

```
builder.RegisterType<ExecutionContextResolverElsterRuntime>()
       .As<IExecutionContextResolver>()
       .InstancePerOwned<**Workstation**>();
builder.RegisterType<ExecutionContextResolverElsterRuntimeV2>()
       .As<IExecutionContextResolver>()
       .InstancePerOwned<**WorkstationManager**>();
```

Update the container dynamically is no option because of parallel running process.

Comment: Could you describe what you want to do ?

Comment: I need a new instance of executioncontextresolver in the lifetime of "workStationmanger" and "workstation". This instance have to life and will e resolve over the complete lifecycle. The insatnace per owned seemd to be the right way when I have only one parent child eg. "Workstation"

Comment: It sounds like you want InstancePerDependency, which is the default behavior.

Comment: No, the instance have to life in thr scope of the statiom or Manager. This is not oer dependency

Comment: Hi, nobody have an idea how to register by differnt "InstancePerOwend"ß